# Undefined variable: _SESSION [CORE/src/Network/Session.php CakePHP 3.0

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3.0, and uploaded it to the server, it was working fine in local but somehow after uploading it to server it shows error

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: _SESSION
>   [CORE/src/Network/Session.php, line 438]

If any have idea about that please help me. I am still trying to solve it.
I have also tried to put `session_start();` in `AppController` and many other places but then it goes blank.

Comment: It is obviously because you don't have your `session_start();`, put it a the beginning of script

Comment: hello @xNeyte,I have tried that also but not working with CakePHP :(

Comment: So _where_ and _how_ exactly (please show some code) are you trying to write to the session so that this error is being triggered?

Comment: I have tried to put it in Session.php,AppController.php and also in some view files.

Comment: This is anything but _exact_. Again, please show some code. Seeing the session configuration wouldn't hurt too, at least whether `session.use_cookies` is enabled.

Comment: Its not executing the further code.There is nothing to show in code.and yes   session.use_cookies is enabled.Please let me know if anything you want to know more about this

Comment: It doesn't matter whether something isn't being executed, in order to be able to give you any advice without just shooting in the dark, people need to see what your code is doing. For example, the session will not be started when you are trying to write to it after [**headers have already been sent**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.1/src/Network/Session.php#L318-L320). But again, that's all just shooting in the dark, and not really suited for SO.

Comment: Thanks,Thats sure its not error of "header already sent",The code is perfect and it s working fine my local server,Its just not working fine on server.If you want any file name it or any specific code that you want to see.

Comment: I'm not talking about that "headers already sent" error, I'm talking about logic in the CakePHP session wrapper that silently (without triggering an error) will prevent the session from being started in case headers have already been sent.

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue.. I would suggestion checking your `app.php` and post the `['Session']` value here....

Comment: in app.php I have
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
  ] and its correct.And if I tried to start session it goes blank or to post then it show error same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue,
Its when I was uploading the files to servers it was automatically appending the white blank lines at the end of the AppController and also another controller files.

So when I removed the blank lines from that files it is working fine again

```
    //To detect the file which have issue or extra space or early header start
//File location : vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Session.php 
    public function write($name, $value = null)
            {
                if (empty($name)) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!$this->started()) {
                    $this->start();
                }

                $write = $name;
                if (!is_array($name)) {
                    $write = [$name => $value];
                }

                //remove the comment from bottom line and run your code it will 
                //show you the exact file from where you have to remove the blank space
                //session_start();
                $data = $_SESSION ?: [];
                foreach ($write as $key => $val) {
                    $data = Hash::insert($data, $key, $val);
                }

                $this->_overwrite($_SESSION, $data);
            }
```

Small issue but took long time to detect it,hope this will help you all.

Answer (score -2):

Place this in your php.ini file on your server

```
session.save_path = “/var/tmp”
```

Answer (score -3):

You need make sure to start the session at the top of every PHP file where you want to use the $_SESSION superglobal. Like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['youritem'];
?>
```

You forgot the Session HELPER.

Check this link : book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html

Comment: If you using cakephp using session_start() right left and centre is going to piss you right off. Look into using Cakephp Session Helper.

Comment: I am using CakePHP 3.0 and in that SessionComponent is deprecated.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html Configure object alternative. I use this even when i am developing in cakephp 2.0